# Python pandas if row contains string add to table

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a spreadsheet that looks as follows:

[image]

my goal is to print out which "hmi" controls which "az", which is indicated by an "x" in its corresponding column. Example based on the above spreadsheet:

- HMI1 controls AZ1
- HMI2 controls AZ2
- HMI3 controls AZ3
- HMI4 controls AZ3

etc..

My idea output that i can work with and sort to an output excel sheet would be(where "X" is the corresponding number):

```
HMIX | AZX
```

ive imported the spreadsheet with pd.read_excel and my thought was using the following code to format it, however i think im close but on the wrong path:

```
    for index, row in dfConfig.iterrows():
        if row["az1"] != "NaN":
            print(row["hmi_number"])
```

Comment: If the blanks were imported as `NaN` you might be able to just `dfConfig.stack()`, which will drop the NaN and then your MultiIndex is tuples of (hmi_number, Col_name_with_X_in_cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over rows first, thank over columns, if you find the `x`, print the row and the columns.

```
for i, row in dfConfig.iterrows():
    for col in dfConfig:
        if row[col] == 'x':
            print(f'HMI{row["hmi_number"]} controls {col}')
```

Comment: this actually works perfectly. Side quest, is there a way to store which HMI controls which AZ into a variable so i can pipe it out to a table?

Comment: in the last "if" you can access the current hmi_number using row["hmi_number"], and the current azX in the "col" variable. 
BTW @Scott Boston has a faster, more efficient answer if you need, mine is more understandable for someone not too practical with pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Given df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hmi_number':np.arange(1,10),
                  'az1':['x']+[np.nan]*8,
                  'az2':[np.nan]+['x']+[np.nan]*7,
                  'az3':[np.nan]*2+['x']*2+[np.nan]*5,
                  'az4':[np.nan]*4+['x']*2+[np.nan]*3,
                  'az5':[np.nan]*6+['x']*2+[np.nan],
                  'az6':[np.nan]*8+['x']})
```

Try this:

```
for hmi, az in (df.set_index('hmi_number')=='x').dot(df.columns[1:]).iteritems():
    print(f'HMI{hmi} controls {az}')
```

Output:

```
HMI1 controls az1
HMI2 controls az2
HMI3 controls az3
HMI4 controls az3
HMI5 controls az4
HMI6 controls az4
HMI7 controls az5
HMI8 controls az5
HMI9 controls az6
```

Comment: this approach also works perfectly. im not too keen to pandas so can you explain to me what exactly is going on in the df statement?

Comment: Sure, we are using matrix muliplication to get those column headings into the dataframe.  We create a boolean matrix by comparing the dataframe to 'x', then we multiply by the column headings to produce a matrix with 'hmi_number' as the row index and the column headings as the values at that row.  Then we iterate over each row using iteritems and print.

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for something that checks if something is a string try this

```
>>> currentColumn = "x"
>>> isinstance(currentColumn, str)
True
>>> isinstance(currentColumn, int)
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is based on `stack()` method and then accessing index by list comprehension. Given above dataframe `df`:

`[print(f"HMI{x} controls {y}") for x,y in df.set_index("hmi_number").stack().index]`

Solution is fast and very compact.